# How to create a dynamic class with Expression

Tags: c#-4.0, expression

I want to do something like this :

```
Expression<Func<dynamic>> newClassExpression = //Create a new anonymous object
foreach (Expression exp in subSelector)
{
   //Create a new property into newClassExpression to affect exp.Compile().Invoke(f)
}
return newClassExpression.Compile(); //Return here the code for creation of the new class
```